# extract the text using Selenium WebDriver when page source is not shown fully

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

How to extract the text using Selenium WebDriver when page source is not shown fully? 
or

how do you deal with it using your tools?

It looks like this site have blocked the extracting the fields manually,

and only allows to manually download preprocessed CSV file.

When I try to check the searched data in Page Source (Ctrl+U or Strg+U) I do not see the table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driverurl = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb"

driver.get(driverurl)
driver.find_element_by_id("btnButton").click()

Name = "John"
DocType = "DEED TRANSFERS OF REAL PROPERTY (D)"
RecordDate = "8/1/2017"

driver.find_element_by_id("SearchOnName").send_keys(Name)

driver.find_element_by_id("DocTypesDisplay-input").clear()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("DocTypesDisplay-input").send_keys(DocType)

driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateFrom").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateFrom").send_keys(RecordDate)
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateTo").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateTo").send_keys(RecordDate)

driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearch").click()

html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

Row = soup.findAll("tr", { "class" : "t-state-selected" })[0].findAll("td")
SearchedName = Row[1].get_text()
RecordDate   = Row[5].get_text()
print SearchedName
print RecordDate

# driver.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 34, in
>   
>       Row = soup.findAll("tr", { "class" : "t-state-selected" })[0].findAll("td") IndexError: list index out of range

really the list has more elements

I would like to automate saving the generated CSV files, or write a bot to go through all the rows and save to my csv file.

I simplified the question and ask only how to extract any 1-2 fields from the 1 st row.

open https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName

or

https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeDocT‌​ype

and see.

Comment: What data are you trying to extract?

Comment: @Dan-Dev open https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName
or https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeDocType
and see,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I got an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I added two lines of code around your existing line like this to fix it:

```
...
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearch"))
driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearch").click()
sleep(10) # maybe it doesn't need this long
....
```

Also it looks to me like the class t-state-selected is not applied to an element until it is clicked so I changed:

```
Row = soup.findAll("tr", { "class" : "t-state-selected" })[0].findAll("td")
```

to

```
Row = soup.findAll("tr")[1].findAll("td")
```

Now it outputs:

```
JOHNSON,BRIAN S
08/01/2017 02:05:25
```